# Cannot start iptables on RHEL 7

Tags: iptables, rhel7

I am trying to use iptables on a RHEL7.  I have performed the following:

```
systemctl mask firewalld
systemctl stop firewalld
yum install iptables-services
systemctl enable iptables
systemctl start iptables
```

But the last line errors:

```
Job for iptables.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status iptables.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

journalctl -u service-name.service
-- No entries --
```

and `journalctl -xe`

```
Jan 13 12:30:03 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit iptables.service entered failed state.
Jan 13 12:30:03 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: iptables.service failed.
Jan 13 12:30:03 localhost.localdomain polkitd[10240]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:27798:561438909 (system bus name :1.22082, object path /org/freedesktop/P
lines 1222-1263/1263 (END)
```

Which only tells me it failed, not the cause, and I don't know what [Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25527790/explanation-of-polkitd-unregistered-authentication-agent) means or if it's related.  I believe it is because it always follows the iptables error lines.  But I don't know what this means, or specifically how to remedy it. Nor which is cause and which is effect.

**Additionally**:

```
sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT

sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      28
```

and `iptables-restore` hangs.

[This other post is no help](https://serverfault.com/questions/511375/cannot-start-iptables-service).

**Resolved:**

I am not sure exactly what was the real cause, handle locks or whatever, but after a couple of reboots and running `iptables-restore`, I am now able to get the service started.

**How to I get iptables services started?**

Comment: do you disable ipv6 too?.....

Comment: @JacobEvans - No, but I am not using IPv6 either at the moment.

Comment: did you try `systemctl daemon-reload` before `systemctl start iptables`

Comment: @JacobEvans no but I just tried with same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer I know, but I had a similar issue and a reboot fixed it. The service was started on boot and then I could stop and start as normal.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but same results.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work

Comment: After a couple more reboots and restore attempts, everything is now working.  So, I am accepting this as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Run in sequence it worked.
service iptables save
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl disable  firewalld
systemctl start iptables
systemctl status iptables
systemctl enable iptables